# Bigquery generage week range starts from every day of the year

Tags: sql, date, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to generage a DimDate table including from 2023-01-01 to 2024-12-31 (maybe more years in the future). A range_start should always start from the first day of the year like 2023-01-01. Interval is a week. Don't consider weekname. And the last week of the year should include the rest of the year like in sample.

Sample:

| fulldate | range_start | range_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-07 |
| 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-07 |
| 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-07 |
| 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-07 |
| 2023-01-05 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-07 |
| 2023-01-06 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-07 |
| 2023-01-07 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-07 |
| 2023-01-08 | 2023-01-08 | 2023-01-14 |
| 2023-01-09 | 2023-01-08 | 2023-01-14 |
| 2023-01-10 | 2023-01-08 | 2023-01-14 |
| 2023-01-11 | 2023-01-08 | 2023-01-14 |
| 2023-01-12 | 2023-01-08 | 2023-01-14 |
| 2023-01-13 | 2023-01-08 | 2023-01-14 |
| 2023-01-14 | 2023-01-08 | 2023-01-14 |
| balabala.. |  |  |
| 2023-12-17 | 2023-12-17 | 2023-12-23 |
| 2023-12-18 | 2023-12-17 | 2023-12-23 |
| 2023-12-19 | 2023-12-17 | 2023-12-23 |
| 2023-12-20 | 2023-12-17 | 2023-12-23 |
| 2023-12-21 | 2023-12-17 | 2023-12-23 |
| 2023-12-22 | 2023-12-17 | 2023-12-23 |
| 2023-12-23 | 2023-12-17 | 2023-12-23 |
| 2023-12-24 | 2023-12-24 | 2023-12-31 |
| 2023-12-25 | 2023-12-24 | 2023-12-31 |
| 2023-12-26 | 2023-12-24 | 2023-12-31 |
| 2023-12-27 | 2023-12-24 | 2023-12-31 |
| 2023-12-28 | 2023-12-24 | 2023-12-31 |
| 2023-12-29 | 2023-12-24 | 2023-12-31 |
| 2023-12-30 | 2023-12-24 | 2023-12-31 |
| 2023-12-31 | 2023-12-24 | 2023-12-31 |
| 2024-01-01 | 2024-01-01 | 2024-01-07 |
| 2024-01-02 | 2024-01-01 | 2024-01-07 |
| 2024-01-03 | 2024-01-01 | 2024-01-07 |
| 2024-01-04 | 2024-01-01 | 2024-01-07 |
| 2024-01-05 | 2024-01-01 | 2024-01-07 |
| 2024-01-06 | 2024-01-01 | 2024-01-07 |
| 2024-01-07 | 2024-01-01 | 2024-01-07 |
| 2024-01-08 | 2024-01-08 | 2024-01-14 |
| 2024-01-09 | 2024-01-08 | 2024-01-14 |
| 2024-01-10 | 2024-01-08 | 2024-01-14 |
| 2024-01-11 | 2024-01-08 | 2024-01-14 |
| 2024-01-12 | 2024-01-08 | 2024-01-14 |
| 2024-01-13 | 2024-01-08 | 2024-01-14 |
| 2024-01-14 | 2024-01-08 | 2024-01-14 |
| balabala.. |  |  |

I ask ChatGPT so many times and the final version is like：

```
WITH
  dates AS (
  SELECT
    date AS fulldate
  FROM
    UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2023-01-01', '2024-12-31')) AS date )
SELECT
  fulldate,
  cast(DATE_ADD(fulldate, INTERVAL -(MOD(EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK
        FROM
          fulldate) - 1, 7)) DAY) as date) AS range_start,
  cast(DATE_ADD(fulldate, INTERVAL (7 - MOD(EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK
        FROM
          fulldate) - 1, 7)) DAY) - INTERVAL 1 DAY as date) AS range_end
FROM
  dates;
```

Which is good from the start but bad in the last week of 2023. And 2024 doesn't restart from Jan 1st. Is there a perfect script to solve this problem? Otherwise I can only use excel to input the record manually which could be painful...

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL server of you are using bigquery?

Answer (score 0):

I write my own solution. Though it's for one year. But it's better than the code that the stupid chatgpt gave me.

```
BEGIN
declare var_year_start date;
declare var_year_end date;

set var_year_start = '2023-01-01';
set var_year_end = '2023-12-31';

WITH
  dates AS (
  SELECT
    date AS fulldate,
    date AS range_start,
    CAST(DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 6 DAY) AS date) AS range_end
  FROM
    UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(var_year_start, var_year_end, INTERVAL 7 day)) AS date 
),
  b AS (
  SELECT
    fulldate,
    range_start,
    CASE
      WHEN DATE_DIFF(CAST(var_year_end AS date), range_end,day) < 7 THEN var_year_end
    ELSE
    range_end
  END
    AS range_end
  FROM
    dates
  WHERE
    CASE
      WHEN DATE_DIFF(CAST(var_year_end AS date), range_start,day) < 7 THEN 'remove'
    ELSE
    'keep'
  END
    <> 'remove' )
SELECT
  get_day AS fulldate,
  EXTRACT(DAYofweek FROM  get_day) as a,
  range_start,
  range_end
FROM
  b
LEFT JOIN
  UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(var_year_start, var_year_end)) AS get_day
ON
  get_day BETWEEN b.range_start
  AND b.range_end;

end;
```

Comment: Ono, not working for 2024...